# SharePoint Designer 2010 does not save changes

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I edit a master page with SharePoint Designer, then I save changes and then I close SharePoint Designer. When I open that master page again, the last changes don't show up.

Comment: what are you changing?

Comment: A simple div ... for example 
<div id="sesion">Bienvenidos  |<strong>Accesos directos a nuestra Intranet    >>> </strong> </div>

Comment: you have to publish the master page to see the difference

Comment: Check in and Publish your master page

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. After i made a change to a custom master template, saved and checked in then re-opened all changes had disappeared. I found the actual changes were being applied and visible on the webpage.

The issue appears to have something to do with the local cache in your profile. Clearing this resolves the issue.
Delete the data here: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache`

Ref.- http://www.tompuleo.com/2009/04/sharepoint-designer-says-i-have-file.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the master page before editing and check in after the changes have been made. Also turn on the publishing feature for the master page library. The changes will be published as a major version.

Answer (score 0):

When you re-open the page, try hitting the green refresh button at the top left. That should sync Designer with any changes on the server.